# Can't figure out the right linq query for this

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, winforms, linq

I want to generate a list in my datagrid view box. I have the userId, **uId**, and i want to at first search for the user in the database using the id and then display the user's corresponding username and rolename. How can i do this?
Below, i've attempted to search for user using UserId, but since i'm new to this i know that the rest of the code after brackets isn't right. I could use some help with the syntax. Thanks

```
var list = _db.AspNetUserRoles.FirstOrDefault(w => w.UserId == uId)
            {
                w.AspNetUser.UserName,
                w.AspNetRole.Name
            });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` doesn't return an enumerable, it's a single item. If you want to project the items you need to use `Select` and why use a DataGrid for a single user's information? Why not just two label controls?

Comment: thanks for the correction! i'm using the datagrid because i need to display changes as i add to the user role-name list or any other changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Where` clause instead of `FirstOrDefault`, because `FirstOrDefault` returns the first element of a sequence. After the `Where` clause use `Select` to make a anonymous class with `UserName` and `Name` properties:

```
var list = _db.AspNetUserRoles.Where(w => w.UserId == uId).Select(w => new
            {
                UserName = w.AspNetUser.UserName,
                Name = w.AspNetRole.Name
            }).ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: @SlavenTojić, hey Slaven Good catch, I missed `Select` clause. +1 for select clause. Today I learnt use of select clause

Answer (score 0):

As lan Mercer said `FirstOrDefault` returns *first or default **(single)*** value, if you want list of elements which satisfies condition provided by you then use `where`.

```
var list = _db.AspNetUserRoles.Where(w => w.UserId == uId)
            {
                Uname = w.AspNetUser.UserName,
                Name = w.AspNetRole.Name
            });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```